# Joint Embedding Property for modules?

Tags: logic, category-theory, modules, representation-theory, model-theory

I have read that the theory of groups and monoids has Joint embedding property. By Joint embedding property we mean that for any two models A,B there is a model C such that A,B can be embedded into C. This is clearly false for fields since a field embedding would respect characteristics.

I am wondering if we have Joint embedding property for Modules over any given ring i.e. can we extend this property of category of groups to these groups as modules over some ring R. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For two $R$-modules $M_1,M_2$, both $M_1$ and $M_2$ embed into the direct sum $M_1 \oplus M_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was mistaken thinking of direct products... I see. The answer is affirmative: Theory of modules overy any choice of ring R has JEP.

Comment: @YonedaLemma The direct product and direct sum of two modules are always isomorphic...